# What kind of key can I use to mimic querying by multiple children in Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tree of objects in Firebase that I'd like to sort by number of likes then title. I'd like to use querying to paginate through the results. Unfortunately, I can't query by multiple children in Firebase. Is there a way to combine these two fields (number of likes and title) into a single key? Or maybe there's a better way to structure the data than:

```
object1:
    numberOfLikes: n
    title: s
object2:
    numberOfLikes: n
    title: s
```

I'm working in iOS.

Comment: You've neither mentioned nor tagged the SDK client you are using. Is it JS, iOS or Android?

Comment: Thanks, just edited. I'm on iOS.

Comment: If you want to search on full title and number of likes, you'd combine them as `s_<n>` and could then search for matching titles and a range of likes. Is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question in your question!

```
object1:
    numberOfLikes: 10
    title: 22
    likes_title: 10_22
object2:
    numberOfLikes: 17
    title: 41
    likes_title: 17_41
object3:
    numberOfLikes: 10
    title: 17
    likes_title: 10_17
```

ordered by likes_title will give you

```
object3
object1
object2
```

This is a really solid way to expand the query and order capability of firebase with very low overhead and without additional libraries.